# INSERT INTO table that contains foreign key

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms

I'm trying to insert values into a table called `Division` and it has a foreign key called `id_dep` from the table `Departement`. The problem is that I couldn't insert values into the `Division` table because of the foreign key. I searched the internet and found that I can't insert values into a foreign key directly but through a `Select`. I made some changes and my command looks like this:

```
string req = "INSERT INTO DIVISION VALUES(SELECT id_dep FROM Departement WHERE libelle='"+dep+"','" + id + "','" + lib + "')";
```

Now I'm getting a problem about syntax error. How to resolve that?

Comment: Paste the Syntax error here..

Comment: You have multiple commas in the where clause. Write out a copy of the sql as you expect it should be.

Comment: here is the syntax error "Erreur de syntaxe. dans l'expression 'SELECT id_dep FROM Departement WHERE libelle='Informatique''."

Comment: I have noticed many things wrong in your above statement. first is Where clause are separated by commas(in `WHERE` you always use `and`/`or`/`Like` operators. Secondly, in `INSERT` using `SELECT` you never need a keyword 'VALUES`, instead you have to select that columns which you want to insert.

Answer (score 3):

Use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` syntax,

```
INSERT INTO DIVISION (colName, colName2, colName3)
SELECT id_dep, @id, @lib
FROM Departement
WHERE libelle = @dep
```

Always parameterized the query to avoid sql injection.

Comment: @user3533921, is not this answer? what is wrong with that which you have not marked it as answer?